# Failed to run a Java app with Git Bash

Tags: java, git, bash, classpath

I downloaded [SymmetricDS](https://www.symmetricds.org/), a tool for Database replication and tried to run it on my Windows7 machine. The program can be launched from command line and it works with Windows Terminal. However I always prefer `Git Bash` for command line stuff. When I run command `sym` though, I got error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jumpmind.symmetric.SymmetricLauncher
```

This tool is written in Java. I have JDK 1.8 installed. Git Bash inherits all environmental variables including `$PATH` and `$JAVA_HOME` from Windows. But why is it complaining about not finding the class?

The `sym` command is really running the following command:

```
exec "$SYM_JAVA" $SYM_OPTIONS -cp "$CLASSPATH" org.jumpmind.symmetric.SymmetricLauncher "$@"
```

All the jars are located in `lib` under the root directory of the application. The classpath is defined in a `sym.service.conf` inside `conf` directory:

```
# Java Classpath
wrapper.java.classpath.1=patches
wrapper.java.classpath.2=patches/*
wrapper.java.classpath.3=lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=web/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

# Application main class and arguments
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.jumpmind.symmetric.SymmetricLauncher
```

I added `echo $CLASSPATH` right before the `exec` to print out the class path and it did seem to get all of them right:

```
/c/Users/dnj0109/Apps/symmetric-server-3.8.29/patches:
/c/Users/dnj0109/Apps/symmetric-server-3.8.29/patches/*:
/c/Users/dnj0109/Apps/symmetric-server-3.8.29/lib/*:
/c/Users/dnj0109/Apps/symmetric-server-3.8.29/web/WEB-INF/lib/*
```

Answer (score 16):

That could be related [to this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/E16M9hCW2_4):

> On Windows, the path separator is a semicolon ('`;`' instead of '`:`').
>   Don't ask why. Traditionally, the semicolon is interpreted by the Bash as
>   the command separator, so you'll have to escape it:

```
$ java -cp lib/clojure-1.1.0.jar\;lib/clojure-contrib-1.1.0.jar
```

> If you wonder why it works with PATH: MSys has special handling routines
>   for that.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason that a java app may run in a Windows CMD shell but not in a Windows git bash shell is that the classpath used to run the app contains one of the following:

- relative paths (e.g. `../foo`)
- network drives (e.g. `//servername/bah`

See:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1028